# How to use paypal for products belongs to several sellers in a cart from a one transaction?

Tags: paypal, payment-processing

Friends, I am developing a website for product sales.Products can be submitted by different sellers.So if a buyer add different products from different sellers for his cart,I need to do the paypal process in a single transaction.

I have no problem with if the items are belongs to one seller as below

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="abc@abc.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name 1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="1.75">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item Name 2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="2.50">
<input type="submit" value="PayPal">
</form>
```

But if items are from different sellers,that makes me trouble. Do i need to loop all the items and submit each by each or Can you advise me to overcome this problem thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try PayPal adaptive payments "parallel payments" APIs - https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro

You can download sample code/SDK from above same URL.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I will come back after checking your link